# How to find equivalent standard library functions in Coq

Tags: coq

I had the need for the following theorem

```
Lemma cons_eq {A}:
  forall x (l l' : list A), x :: l = x :: l' -> l = l'.
  intros.
  inversion H. auto.
Qed.
```

Is this theorem available from the standard library? I did not find it through `Search (_ :: _ = _ :: _ -> _ = _)`

Or even better if there was `l = l' <-> x::l = x::l'`. During a proof I came upon a goal of `x::l = x::l'` which I wanted to rewrite to `l = l'`

Comment: I can only find `app_inv_head`, which is `l ++ l1 = l ++ l2 -> l1 = l2`. I think the reason it wasn't introduced is that you can get `l = l'` with a single tactic, as you did. To change `x::l = x::l'` to `l = l'` you can use `constructor`, IIRC.

Comment: @dyukha I don't think that's `constructor`. For the lemma in the question, cleaner than `inversion` is [`injection`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.injection), here `injection H as H`. The other direction is [`f_equal`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.f-equal). I do agree that the simplicity of "just one tactic" is probably why these lemmas don't exist as their own definitions.